# Trying to get remoting appender to work in log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, remoting

I am trying to get the Remoting appender to work in log4net.  I have implemented the method shown in [these posts](http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Remote-Appender-td22810.html) and I see the server object listening on the correct port, but I cannot get the client object to actually make the remoting connection.  Client and server are both running on the same machine (my development box) so it should not be a firewall issue.  I implemented the TimedRemotingAppender as show in the posts, and I can set a breakpoint on the LogEvents method, and see that it hits the breakpoint whenever I call log4net, but nothing ever appears at the server.  I'm pretty sure I have the config files correct.

Any log4net gurus out there, is there a trick to getting this to work?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: What version of log4net are you using?

Comment: 1.2.10 - I know there is a new release out, but I have been told by my boss to "freeze" third party products at this point, unless there is a good excuse (do you think 1.2.12 would make any difference?)  Thanks.

Comment: Exact same version (identical dlls) for both client and server, since at this point things have only been run on my development machine.

Comment: At first, I thought this sounded like something similar I ran into a while back, but I don't think that's the case. Have you tried any debug steps in log4net itself to see if that narrows down where the problem lies? http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx

Comment: @PeterHowe where can we view the logged messages of remoting appender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out that it is not really a log4net issue.  I made a change elsewhere in my code, changing this line of code:

```
RemotingConfiguration.Configure(null, true);
```

To this:

```
RemotingConfiguration.Configure(null, false);
```

and data started flowing.  I'm not sure what extra code I would have to write to get the ["secure" version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of remoting connections working, but any machine we would do this on is already behind the corporate firewall, so I may not have to fuss with security.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: currently I have also implemented RemotingAppender but I did not find any code on net I am also in need of that if you can provide me the code may my problem will be solve thanks @Peter Howe